# Como clonar um Branch no Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, github

Gostaria de saber como posso clonar um Branch do GitHub no Android Studio, pois quando eu clono o Projeto, na tela inicial, vem apenas a versão padrão do repositório.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri que o Android Studio automáticamente clona todas as Branchs de uma vez só. Para acessa-las, basta ir em:

VCS --> Git --> **Branches...**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]